# How to Ask is hard to find

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It's common to refer new posters to the "How to Ask" page, but as far as I can see, it's only a box shown on the page when you're asking a question.  If they ignore that and then get told to see "How to Ask", they can't find it.  If they go back to edit their question, I think it shows "How to Edit" instead.

On one stackexchange site, I was once told to read the About because the commenter said my question was off topic for the site (spoiler alert - it wasn't).  But that was also hard to find.

Can't each site have their "About" and "How to Ask" pages shown as links somewhere at the top of the page?

Comment: Where do you think it should be shown that it currently isn't being shown?

Comment: Here's a list of ways to get there, not sure if it's comprehensive. 1. When asking your first question you're linked to the page and forced to indicate that you've read it before you can continue 2. the sidebar when asking any question. 3. in any close reason if your question is closed 4. in an auto comment by a user specifically directing you there (there's a shortcut to link to it) 5. if you end up being warned for posting low quality contributions, the message links to it. 6. The message if you end up question banned. 7. The top bar has links to the help center, how to ask being among them.

Comment: The help link at the top doesn't have How to Ask directly.  There's Help Center, but searching for How To Ask on that page doesn't show it.

Comment: The help center has a whole section on how to ask good questions, and it's the first section.  I find it hard to believe that someone would get to that page and then not be able to find information on how to ask a good question.

Comment: @dwilliss Last hop from ["The Tour"](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and receive the _Informed_ badge? Do people read?

Comment: What I fail to get here is... how much MORE do you need it linked? Servy showed 7 different ways you are offered that article. Do we need that many more?

Comment: @Patrice [50 ways to leave your lover](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTiyLuZOs1A) ;-)

Comment: I agree that this site could stand to be a little more newcomer-friendly.

Comment: To find How to ask, 1/. Go to home page 2/. Find a bad question 3/. Look at comment! 4/. If there is no ask link, please review the question and add    `[ask]` . And before you know you will improve your knowledge on How to ask simply by reviewing, Applying the Ask notice to real case scenario

Comment: I think the biggest problem is that I've seen comments telling people to see "How to Ask" that were *not* links to the how to ask page.  Maybe those people didn't use the automatic response.  If you go to the Help Center, yes, there's a whole section on asking questions, but the "How do I ask a good question" is hidden at the bottom where you would have to expand to see it. It could be pinned at the top.

Comment: @dwilliss It's easy to find if they're even bothering to do so. Top section to read still is [***What topics can I ask about here?***](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). And that's good so IMO. Asking an even _good question_ goes beyond that.

Comment: It's bewildering how so many responses miss the mark. The basic request is about making a very commonly-referenced link more prominent. Listing multiple ways to access the page, nor the many reasons why a new user "should" find it on their own, does nothing to address the fact that there are still many new users which need to be directed to a **very specific page** which is referenced over and over again in comments. Experienced users apparently trust that page. Many existing elements on Stack Overflow are technically unnecessary and were added for convenience / intuitiveness. Why not this?

Comment: @Servy says you "find it hard to believe that someone would ... not be able to find information", but the point is that many new users need direction before they go browsing the help center on their own or before one of the other events in your list happen.  You have not answered the key question of _"why do so many experienced users find it necessary to purposefully direct new users to the very specific 'How to Ask' page in comments if the new users were already being directed there to start with?"_  The partial answers is that they are not being directed there despite your list.

Comment: @CPerkins Is it that they can't find it, or that they choose to not read it when it's given to them, or that they choose to not look for it?  This is the first time I've *ever* seen someone say that they couldn't find it.  I've seen lots of people talk about why they shouldn't have to read it, or won't read it, or don't even consider the possibility that there is something they should be reading before asking a question.

Comment: @CPerkins Who is missing the mark?  The question has stated that people can't find the page, without demonstrating why this is the case, or *that* it's the case, has stated that it should be more prominent, but failed to indicate how it could be more prominent, or how all of the *existing* references to it (of which there are a *lot*) are inadequate.  That is all very important information for such a feature request that's simply missing.

Answer (score 3):

I seriously disagree that more efforts should be taken onto that.

> It's common to refer new posters to the "How to Ask" page ...

Yes, that's one of the very first entry points they are referred to, even without interference of comments.
I think it's quite prominent already:

[image]

New users signing up the site, who really care to read and understand [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) will even be awarded the [informed badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed)

> If they go back to edit their question, I think it shows "How to Edit" instead.

New OPs often need to be nudged about that referring to the `[**edit**]` button in the comment markup. So let it be so ...
Could be standing out **fat style** though as shown above, and maybe an additional tooltip appearing to say:

> > Consider to [**edit**] your question for clarification, instead of responding with another comment.

when they are going to the comment (reply) edit box instead.

---

The primary question is IMO:

***How should we improve to communicate with people who don't bother to read at a purely text oriented site?***

Kind of a *rhetorical* question though, needs some solid (nice!!) sarcasm to handle that sanely.

---

> [@deceze♦ *"How about a 10-second animated GIF involving emojis and kittens for the millennial crowd…? "*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362993/how-to-ask-is-hard-to-find#comment555252_362996)

No, I don't believe that

- adding *emojis* like [image: An SO style _poop emoji_]
- or seemingly cute *animated kitten gifs*[image: Cute animated GIF of a kitten getting between tired and angry]

would really help to solve that problem.

---

### My personal conclusion:

<kbd>[feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)</kbd>:

> Don't allow newly accounted users (minimum membership 1h or so, better a day or two) to ask a question unless they earned the [<kbd>Informed●</kbd>  badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed).

As a workaround for that FR isn't yet realized, just flag/vote those useless questions,- coming up because lack of attention -, for closure, and maybe give them a downvote along.

Comment: You could put it in blaring flashing red and blue pop ups that wouldn't let you reply until the pop up was all the way scrolled down with a "I read and understand" checkbox is checked, yet people who don't bother to read will still glaze over it and post while ignoring the rules. To your question, I have no answer, I don't know if it can be done.

Comment: I think the main thing missing in answers to questions like these is contempt. Maybe we could find a way to easily add that somewhere?

Comment: How about a 10-second animated GIF involving emojis and kittens for the millennial crowd…? 

Comment: @deceze http://cdn6.gurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/3.gif

Comment: +1 for red circle and pointer arrow....!!! Nice drawing...

Comment: About the feature request, (I remember someone said that) for the "bad" new users, they would not care anyway whatever you do; and for the "good" new users they think that's too much.

Comment: _"I think it's quite prominent already"_ - and then you show a screenshot of the text _"Looking for more in-depth information on the site?"_. No, they are not looking for that, they want their damn question answered.

Comment: I am a simple man. I see a kitten; I upvote.